# Truncated mean, Student T distribution, 1000 observations - R

Tags: r, distribution, t-test

I have a question which requires me to write a program for simulating n = 1000 observations from the student-t distribution with 7 degrees of freedom.

I believe I have completed this part using

```
R <- rt(n=1000, df=7)
```

The second part of the question asks you to write a program for calculating the truncated mean,  excluding the observations below the 5% and above the 95% of the entire random sample xi from the student-t distribution.

I have some working towards this but am unsure how to incorporate my R(1000 samples of the T distribution)

so far I have got:

```
pt(q=0.95, df= 7, lower.tail = FALSE) + pt(q=-0.95, df= 7, lower.tail = TRUE)
```

I am not sure how to plug in R, and unsure if this is even the correct method, any pointers would be really appreciated, thanks

Comment: This smells like homework. However, you should look at the `quantile()` function. That would give you the 0.05 and 0.95 cutoff values in your vector of `rt(1000, df = 7)`.

Comment: The R function `mean()` has a `trim=` parameter.

Comment: @MrFlick Well that's cool. I've never used that before!